# Using make target name in generated prerequisite

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

All I am wanting to do something along the lines of...

```
some_file.out : ..... ver_$(basename $@).ver:
   .....
```

The `$@` does not expand as expected but only in the rule header. Inside the body of the rule all uses of `ver_$(basename $@).ver` expand as desired. How would I modify this to make it work as desired?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have ellipses eliding too many important parts of your example to provide a full solution.  However, one option is to use [static pattern rules](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Static-Usage.html), like this:

```
some_file.out : %.out : ver_%.ver
        ...
```

If that isn't sufficient you can use secondary expansion, but that's a bigger hammer.