# Rule name as part of prerequisites

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

I have a Makefile to extract the publications for several authors from a BibTex-File and transpose them into a HTML page. I tried to create the Makefile as generic as possible, but now I'm stuck.

Here is what I have at the moment:

```
objects = sts-bib-*.bib
results = Author1 Author2

.PHONY : clean cleanall all $(results)

all : $(results)

$(results) : bib-$@.html

bib-%.bib :
  TMPDIR=. bibtex2html-1.96-osx-x86_64/bib2bib -c 'author : "$*"' -s '$$date' source.bib

bib-%.html : bib-%.bib
  TMPDIR=. bibtex2html-1.96-osx-x86_64/bibtex2html -d -r --nodoc --nobibsource --no-header --no-footer -o bib-$@.html bib-$@.bib

clean :
  -rm $(objects)
```

When I run this, make tells me that there is nothing to be done for *all*. If I run it for a dedicated user, e.g. `make Author1`, it also tells me that for Author1 nothing is to be done. Did I do something wrong with the dependencies of the target? I also tried `$(results) : bib-%.html` and `% : bib-%.html`, all with the same result.

I think the problem lies in the dependency of the target %(result). I want something like [Using make target name in generated prerequisite](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23252948/using-make-target-name-in-generated-prerequisite), but with the complete target name. So I tried `% : % : sts-bib-%.html`, what results in *mixed implicit and static pattern rules.*

Where is my mistake?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The static pattern rule is

```
<list of targets> : <pattern to extract stem from target> : <prereqs>
```

so you need to use:

```
$(results) : % : bib-%.html
```

instead of `$(results) : bib-$@.html`.

Comment: Thanks, that helps, but only one step further. Now it complains: *No rule to make target bib-Author1.html, needed by Author1*. When I `try bib-%.html : %.html : %.bib`, it says: *mixed implicit and static pattern rules*

Comment: That replacement is enough here (in an empty directory) (well and prefixing the build rules with 'echo') to let make run correctly. Whate version of make are you using? Did you make any other changes to the makefile above?

Comment: As this question is a follow up to the one asked here, I just opened another question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25461602/rule-with-static-pattern-fails

Comment: Apparently my comment about static pattern rule targets not containing wildcards was incorrect.