# Rule with static pattern fails

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

I have a makefile to create HTML publication lists for different authors out of one BibTex file. The export is done using bibtex2html and works like a charm. But I'm stuck at the rule naming. I want to have the makefile as generic as possible to only adapt the results list when a new colleague starts or someone finishes his PhD.

The workflow is the following:

1. bib.bib is given
2. Extract the publications from all authors in `results` into seperate files: `bib2bib -c 'author : "$*"' bib.bib'
3. Now there are files for every author, e.g. bib-Author1.bib, bib-Author2.bib, ...
4. Convert the files to html: `bibtex2html -d -r -o bib-$@.html bib-$@.bib`
5. Now there are file called bib-Author1.html, bib-Author2.html, ....

Here is the current makefile I'm stuck with:

```
objects = bib-*.bib
results = Author1 Author2

.PHONY : clean cleanall all $(results)
.INTERMEDIATE : bib-*.bib

all : $(results)

$(results) : % : bib-%.html

bib-%.bib :
  TMPDIR=. bib2bib -c 'author : "$*"' bib.bib

bib-%.html : %.html : %.bib
  TMPDIR=. bibtex2html -d -r -o bib-$@.html bib-$@.bib

#Left the clean and cleanall targets out to shorten the code snippet
```

Right now I call this makefile with a simple `make`, which executes the all target. This calls the `$(result)` target, which calls the bib-%.html target for every author in result.
And here comes the problem: When called, make stops with the error *mixed implicit and static pattern rules.*

What I wanted to do here is take the rule name with the static pattern %.html and have this converted to the prerequisite %.bib. But apparently, I'm doing something wrong. Any help appreciated.

Comment: Just a hunch: what does `make -rR` say?

Comment: You can not have a pattern character (`%`) in all three parts of a static pattern rule. It is not entirely clear to me what you are trying to achieve with the static pattern rule. Could you expand a bit by giving an example of some filenames you are looking to apply this static rule to?

Comment: @ReinierTorenbeek Thanks for your reply. I have the following workflow: bib.bib is given. Extract the publications of one author from bib.bib with `bib2bib -c 'author : "Authorname"' bib.bib`into a file called bib-Authorname.bib. Use this file as input for bibtex2html to have it converted into html using `bibtex2html -o bib-Authorname.html bib-Authorname.bib`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are several things that are wrong -- or at least odd -- in this makefile. Your question is not entirely clear, so some guesswork will be necessary.

First, try rules with simple diagnostic commands, in order to get the sequence right. I think this is what you want:

```
bib-%.bib :
    @echo trying to build $@

bib-%.html : bib-%.bib
    @echo trying to build $@ after $<
```

Then finish one rule and verify that it does what you want:

```
bib-%.bib :
    TMPDIR=. bibtex2html-1.96-osx-x86_64/bib2bib -c 'author : "$*"' -s '$$date' bib.bib

bib-%.html : bib-%.bib
    @echo trying to build $@ after $<
```

Then the other. Your use of automatic variables in the html rule is strange, and I suspect that this is closer to what you intend:

```
bib-%.bib :
    TMPDIR=. bibtex2html-1.96-osx-x86_64/bib2bib -c 'author : "$*"' -s '$$date' bib.bib

bib-%.html : bib-%.bib
    TMPDIR=. bibtex2html-1.96-osx-x86_64/bibtex2html -d -r --nodoc --nobibsource --no-header --no-footer -o $@ $<
```

Comment: Great. This is exactly what I was looking for. I think I got confused by all the static rule stuff I read when creating the $(results) target.